# Establish communication between Universal app and Standalone app developed with Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, win-universal-app, ipc

I have a UWP app and Unity3d app build for Windows. I have a requirement of establishing communication between UWP app and Unity3d app.Both apps will run on same computer.

Development of Unity3d app and Universal app(Windows 10 native app) both are done in C# language.

Communication should involve:

1. Launching and closing Unity3d app from UWP app.
2. Send data from UWP app to Unity3d app.
3. Receive data from Unity3d app to Windows native app.

I had searched for resources for this but unable to find  any. Could someone please share possible ways to achieve the above and resources/examples for those.

Thanks :)

Comment: Both of these apps will be running on the-same computer?

Comment: Yeah both will run on same computer

Answer (score 1):

i did this via an Appservice: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service in your normal xaml app host the app service and let unity consume data from it.

And via protocol activation the apps can start eachother.

Comment: Hey how did you get the AppService and Package name of Unity3d Standalone build

Comment: The unity 3d app targets WSA right? or do you make it a desktop app?

Comment: It is a standalone build and may be pushed to Steam gaming store. If possible I want to make it download and run the .exe of unity app from my UWP app only.Its not windows store app.

Comment: if its just an exe as desktop app you can't use app services. HYou still can use protocol activiation to start each other but active communication between to the two apps will be impossible